# displaying default values in picklist in a vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I had used picklist values Quote type field in Quote:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Qt.Quote_Type__c}"/>
```

I had 3 values a,b,c. I had three quote types i had made 'a' as default value for Quote type and 'b' for Quote type1 and  'c' for Quote type2, but i am not getting default values displaying in vf page. Please some one tell how can i display default values.

Comment: Can you add your current (example) code? This makes it easier for us to understand exactly what you want to know.

Comment: http://writeforce.blogspot.com/2012/11/the-trouble-with-picklists-visualforce.html